# Proposition 7.8 in Atiyah MacDonald

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah and MacDonald, and I am stuck at a detail in Proposition 7.8:

Let $A\subset B\subset C$ be rings. Suppose that $A$ is Noetherian, that $C$ is finitely generated as $A$-algebra and that $C$ is either i) finitely generated as a $B$-module or ii) integral over $B$. Then $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-algebra.

I understand everything in the proof except the first line:
Condition i) and ii) are equivalent in this situation.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Since $C$ is a finitely generated $B$-algebra.

Comment: @user26857. I do not understand, could you please fill in some details?

Comment: finitely generated as algebra + integral = finitely generated as a module.

Comment: @MooS, @ user26857. Of course, I understand now. Thank you.